# BigQuery:Querying Multiple Tables Using a Wildcard Table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am joining multiple tables using Wild table, I want the end date to be current date and start date can be static as shown in below query. But Query returned zero result If I replace hardcoded date to cast(current_date as string).
Please help me on this

```
select * FROM
  `test.session_streaming_*`
WHERE
  _table_suffix BETWEEN '20180101'
  AND cast(current_date as string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_date` returns date in a format `%Y-%m-%d`. You should use FORMAT_DATE function (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format_date) to get correct results:

`FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", current_date)`